# Rails User Mailer: Sending Multiple Emails to a nested resource.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested resource placed in a nested form(for email input), and want to send emails using User Mailer. **I am facing problems   completing following challenges:**

**1) Have 10 input field generated by :fields_for on my invitation/new page in order to send up to 10 emails at a time.**

**2) After submission, cycle through the submitted emails and send an email to each of the submitted entries.**

**3) After emails have been sent, I have no use for the @invitation in the database and want to destroy it.**

So far I have the following code:

**The Models**

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :invitations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitations

end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :scoreboard     

  def send_invitation_email
    UserMailer.send_invitation(self).deliver_now
  end

end
```

**The new.html.erb(invitations)**

```
 <%= form_for [@scoreboard, @invitation] do |f| %> 
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

       <%= f.fields_for :invitations do |invites| %> <!-- this gives me one field. Need 10 fields to accept up to 10 emails -->
         <div>
         <%= invites.label :recipient_email %> 
         <%= invites.text_field :recipient_email %> 
         </div>
       <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

**The Invitations Controller**

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @invitation =  @scoreboard.invitations.build 
    end

    def create
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @invitation = @scoreboard.invitations.build(invitation_params)

    if @invitation.save
      @invitation.send_invitation_email
      flash[:success] = "Invitation sent successfully"
      redirect_to new_scoreboard_invitation_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
    end


private

def invitation_params
    params.require(:invitation).permit(:recipient_email)
end

end
```

When I submit the form, in development log I get the following example code for the invitation:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gS+olMC89noaYs0klYTg6IFgJ2cj4apML/NZbdbu2gia/KXjbPyyvSKrEUoj3rEAWxDknlgNmpnaefy7I6Hk3Q==", "invitation"=>{"invitations"=>{"recipient_email"=>"this@hotmail.com "}}, "commit"=>"Send Invitation", "scoreboard_id"=>"89"}
```

Using the logic that it's a possible collection of hashes within a hash, I came up with the following code in the User Mailer file:

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def send_invitation(invitation)
    @invitation = invitation
    @invitation.each do |key, value|
      value.each do | x, y|
        mail to: y , subject: "You have been invited"
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in Advance!

Optional Bonus Question:

**send_invitation.html.erb**

```
<p>Hi View this Thanks </p> <br></br>
<%= # if someone could provide me a code to a link_to for the url for the scoreboard that the invitation is attached to that would be awesome %>
```

Comment: please provide rake routes output, so I can give you that link_to

Comment: In routes, I have the following: `resources :scoreboards do 
   resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create] end`

Comment: `link_to 'this', scoreboard_url(@invitation.scoreboard)`