# Creating multiple instances through fields_for in a Rails form and how to access the resultant hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I asked a related question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650678/rails-user-mailer-sending-multiple-emails-to-a-nested-resource?noredirect=1#comment57074018_34650678). However, it may have been  confusing as I was unable to get an answer. Therefore I shall ask a simpler question. For my Invitation Model, how do I submit more than 1 invitation at a time and after submission how do I access the data in resultant array/collection of hashes?

The Invitations model has a `:email` string attribute and through form submission, I want to achieve something like the following(I'm assuming that'll be the best setup?):

```
"@invitation" => {
  "@invitations" => [
    {"email" => "example@hotmail.com" },
    {"email" => "example@yahoo.com"},
    {"email" => "example@gmail.com"}
  ]
}
```

The Following is the Code I have so far:

**The Models**

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :invitations

end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :scoreboard     

end
```

**The Invitation#new View**

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @invitation] do |f| %> 
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

       <%= f.fields_for :invitations do |invites| %> <!-- Tried Many things here with no success -->
         <div>
         <%= invites.label :email %> 
         <%= invites.text_field :email %> 
         </div>
       <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

**The Invitations Controller**

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @invitation= @scoreboard.invitations.build 
    end

    def create
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @invitation = @scoreboard.invitations.build(invitation_params)

    if @invitation.save
      flash[:success] = "Invitation sent successfully"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
    end

private

def invitation_params
    params.require(:invitation).permit(:email)
end

end
```

**Invitations#create View**

```
<p> Display all the emails here for all the invitations <p>
```

In my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650678/rails-user-mailer-sending-multiple-emails-to-a-nested-resource?noredirect=1#comment57074018_34650678), I had wanted to access the saved emails so I can mail to them, however if I can figure out how to display all the emails on this view, I can figure out the way the array/hash collections works and using that info, mail them out.

**Edit:**
A scoreboard has been created previously. My goal is to build multiple instances of @invitations that I can associate with the @scoreboard. The reason for this is because I will be mailing to the email addresses in the invitations and would need to provide details about the @scoreboard in the mail body.

Comment: Read and try to implement cocoon, https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed your code again I'll add another answer, as I'm not sure you even need to have the nesting for the Scoreboard.

In your Invitation new view:

```
<%= form_for [@invitation] do |f| %> 
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
     <div>
     <%= f.label :email %> 
     <%= f.text_field :email %> 
     <%= f.hidden_field :scoreboard_id, :value => @scoreboard_id %>
     </div>

    <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your Invitations Controller you can just define the @scoreboard:

```
def new
    @invitation= Invitation.new(scoreboard_id: [:scoreboard_id])
end
```

As it doesn't look like you're doing anything from the Scoreboard controller.

If this doesn't work with the hidden field (not sure whether it's possible depending on how the code is called) then you need to find a way to send the Scoreboard_id through to the new action of the Invitations controller. You can typically send it in the HTTP request or it might be stored in a session on your app already.

Comment: I did some more thinking and I finally understand fully what you're trying to imply here. You're right. I don't need to nest invitations if I can just pass the scoreboard_id through like that. I will try it this way as it's cleaner and accept answer if it works. There's still the issue of having multiple fields to create multiple invitations at a time so I can have an array of :email to work with.

Comment: Check out the Railscast I linked in the answer below - even though you don't need to nest the fields, there are methods Ryan shows in that episode that look at adding new invitations asynchronoulsly on your page (so you'd have a form with 1 email address to invite, and buttons to "add more emails" which would then render another new field to invite another email).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure firstly that your Scoreboard Model can `accept nested attributes for :invitations`.

Then you need to declare that those attributes are part of the permitted hash in the Scoreboard Controller `params.require(:scoreboard).permit(:whatever_scoreboard_attributes_you_have, invitations_attributes: [:email, :etc])`.

Then in your Invitations Controller new action, you need to specify how many invitations you're building to each form. Let's say it's 3:

```
    def new
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
       3.times do @invitation= @scoreboard.invitations.build 
       end
    end
```

Which will allow you to build 3 invitations per Scoreboard.

You should really check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true) too.

Comment: Is it necessary to accept nested attributes even though the form isn't editing anything for the scoreboard class but only the invitation class? Also, the form calls the invitation controller only on submit. The development log has no calls to the scoreboard controller. I actually have a different form to make a new scoreboard. If I use a nested form for [@scoreboard] for invitations, it ends up calling the update method in scoreboards controller and doesn't even call the invitations controller.  Thanks for the railscast btw. I'll check it out.

Comment: It's quite hard to determine what you are trying to do with the Scoreboard in the first place. As far as I can tell from the form, you aren't actually creating a new Scoreboard instance when you're trying to send the invitations. So why are you even using the Scoreboard at all?

Comment: Sorry! New to rails haha. So a scoreboard has already been created earlier. On the scoreboard show page, I have a link to create invitations. On the new page for invitations, I want to build a collection of invitations with emails. I want to associate these invitations with that specific scoreboard so I can sent out mail with the scoreboard details. I will edit the question for clarity. I could explain in greater detail if you're available to chat?

Comment: OK, just look at my other answer then. You can pass through the Scoreboard_id in the URL - so the <%= link_to 'invite', new_invite_path(scoreboard_id: @scoreboard_id) %> will pass the scoreboard_id through, and the code in my other answer should do the rest.

Comment: Now I get the following error: `undefined method `new_invite_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f65c2f64328>:0x007f65c0154ac8>` however scoreboard id does exist on the page in forms of params {"id"=>"90"}. I looked at the session dump and it doesn't exist there.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand what is happening in the brackets `(scoreboard_id: @scoreboard_id)`

Comment: Sorry - have been away. run rake routes in your console to get the specific path. It looks as though it should be new_invitations_path based on your code, I just typed the answer too quickly. The code in the brackets is taking the current scoreboard_id (let's assume you are on the show page for a scoreboard with id = 3) and passing it through the URL  to the new path for the invitation action. So your URL will stop being (www.yoursite.com/invitations/new and will become www.yoursite.com/invitations/new/3) - by bringing through the Scorecard ID in the URL you're able to pass it to the form.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I managed to solve my problem and the invites link only works if I do it like this : <%= link_to "Invite", new_scoreboard_invitation_path(@scoreboard, @invitation) %> Perhaps I was not clear in explaining what I wanted in the question. I will post the answer soon which may give some context.

Comment: That makes sense - that should be the right route, I was too hasty in writing my answer.